# Curl error - Empty reply from server (ssl)

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, osx-leopard

I have problems accessing certain URL using curl on OSX. For other urls I receive response, and for this specific UWL I can receive response from other, ubuntu machine.

I am stucked and do not know what component is broken and do not have any idea, other than upgrading whole system and rould really appreciate any advice that would prevent me do so.

Output of curl:

```
$ curl -v https://subdomain.example.com/pushdispatcher/dispatcher.asp
* About to connect() to subdomain.example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 213.229.251.147... connected
* Connected to subdomain.example.com (213.229.251.147) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Users/bmihelac/.cert/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
  * SSLv2, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  * SSL connection using RC4-MD5
  * Server certificate:
  *      subject: /C=SI/ST=Ljubljana/L=Ljubljana/O=Example d.d./OU=Example/CN=subdomain.example.com
  *      start date: 2011-07-01 00:00:00 GMT
  *      expire date: 2012-07-26 23:59:59 GMT
  *      common name: subdomain.example.com (matched)
  *      issuer: /C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SSL CA
  * SSL certificate verify ok.
  > GET /pushdispatcher/dispatcher.asp HTTP/1.1
  > User-Agent: curl/7.16.4 (i386-apple-darwin9.0) libcurl/7.16.4 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
  > Host: subdomain.example.com
  > Accept: */*
  > 
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
  * SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54
  * Empty reply from server
  * Connection #0 to host subdomain.example.com left intact
  curl: (52) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54
  * Closing connection #0
```

Comment: An SSL problem with a super-old curl and a super-old OpenSSL version. I suggest upgrade the components and try again as the first remedy.

Comment: @daniel Haha, I just noticed myself... You commented a very old question. When it was posted they weren't that old, lmao. But you activated the question and now I found myself answering it. Lol.

Comment: curl 7.16.4 was five years old already in 2012...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server is dropping your connection for some reason.

- Try to add User-Agent headers to the request ( bot detection? )
- Try to connect from other ip ( your ip is in black list? )